# full outer join - intertwined values from joined columns

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

For pure educational purposes, what should I write instead of `*` such that I get only one column `city_name` with a value from either `weather.city` or `city.name`, whichever exists?

```
flav=# select * from weather full outer join cities on weather.city = cities.name;
     city      | temp_lo | temp_hi | prcp |    date    |     name      | location  
---------------+---------+---------+------+------------+---------------+-----------
 San Francisco |      46 |      50 | 0.25 | 1994-11-27 | San Francisco | (-194,53)
 San Francisco |      43 |      57 |    0 | 1994-11-29 | San Francisco | (-194,53)
 Hayward       |      37 |      54 |      | 1994-11-29 |               | 
               |         |         |      |            | Graz          | (90,-90)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

```
SELECT COALESCE(city, name) AS city_name ...
```